# How to display HTML of getElementsByClassName with JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

How to I adjust this code to display the value or favFood?  Works with getElementById but not getElementsByClassName but I want to use a class:

**server file - ProcesssingFileOnServer.php:**

```
<?php

$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj->name = "John"; 
$myObj->favFood = "Pizza";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;

?>
```

**client file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    

<p id="theName"></p>
<div class="bla"></div>

<script>    
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onload = function() {
  const myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  document.getElementById("theName").innerHTML = myObj.name;
  document.getElementsByClassName("bla") = myObj.favFood;
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ProcesssingFileOnServer.php");
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to iterate through the **list** returned by `.getElementsByClassName()` and operate on each element individually.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they use the class, the result is a array.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("bla")
for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].innerHTML = 'asdsadas';
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks works.  Works without the let.  Is let  standard here?

Comment: yes, No problem if you use es6 and you can use const